# Javascript Function. Return в Ajax запросе

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру есть функция:

```
function ajax() {
   $.ajax({
    //тут параметры
    success: function(data) {
    return true;
   }
 });
}

if(ajax()) console.log(true);
```

Проблема заключается в том, success после аякс запроса, не может вернуть true от самой функции. Как можно это решить, не перенося `return true`, в тело функции, после запроса?

Comment: [Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078650/ajax-return-true-false-i-have-implemented-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

объявите любую переменную

```
var eventSend;
```

в том месте где приходят данные вы вызываете функцию

```
eventSend(переменная в которой хранятся пришедшие данные);
```

перед тем как отправить запрос вы добавляете обработчик на это событие

```
eventSend = function(data){//data - это пришедшие данные
//тут любые действия с пришедшими данными
       console.log(true);
    }
```

а далее отправляете запрос

Answer (score -1):

Смог найди для себя решения, опубликую его.

В функции которая делает аякс запрос, мы просто возвращаем полностью его.

```
    function ajax() {
//return объект запроса
      return $.ajax({
        //тут параметры
        success: function(data) {
       }
     });
    }

    if(typeof(ajax()) == 'object') console.log(true);
```

Параметры и проверку возвращаемого результата можно отредактировать под себя. Если мой метод не валидный, прошу объяснить в чем.

Comment: Вы его проверили? Получили `false` в условии `if(typeof(ajax()) == 'object')`? Куда попадает возвращаемый из `success` `true` в `return true;`?